# QNetwork stop connection and retrieve data

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a timeout on QNetwork when reading a URL. If reading the data takes longer than 30 seconds (it not timeout, server is not down, connection is not broken, connection is not closed, connection is still active and I'm still receiving data). I need to stop+close QNetwork after X seconds, even if server is still up and sending data. How can I do that?

Comment: You use a QNetworkReply ?

Comment: @ThibautB. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect a `QTimer` in singleshot mode with your `QNetworkReply` pure virtual slot `abort()`:

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
// connect the timer to the reply
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &networkReply, SLOT(abort())));
// start your timer
timer.start(30000);
```

To get the current data, do it in your implementation of the abort method and then call `close()`.
`QNetworkReply` is a `QIODevice`, so you can use the `readAll()` method.

Comment: @GMXRider, subclass the pure virtual slot [`abort()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#abort) in your implementation, read your wanted data, then close your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The reception of data can be used as an indicator that the connection has been established. This can be used to trigger a timeout.

Thus:

```
void onTimeout(QNetworkReply *reply, int msec, std::function<void(const QByteArray &)> fun) {
  auto call = [=]{
    auto const data = reply->readAll();
    if (!reply->isFinished())
      reply->abort();
    fun(data);
  };
  if (!reply->bytesAvailable()) {
    QPointer<QObject> conn = new QObject(reply);
    // single-shot connection
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, conn, [=](qint64 a, qint64 s){
      if (a && s) {
        QTimer::singleShot(msec, reply, call);
        delete conn;
      }
    });
  }
}
```